# Rounded custom Tab Bar View in React Native + React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Hi I am trying to replicate something like the following in React native and React navigation. Having trouble getting started and even knowing if something like this would be possible. We currently just have a normal square react navigation tab bar but design would like it rounded like this :p

I'm really just looking for high level ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tabBarComponent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig) to make use of a component that looks like this which will replace the existing react-navigation default tabbar component for the TabNavigator